# How to transfer Xcode installations between Macs?

Tags: xcode

I'm going to be away from my home OSX machine and I'm going to be using another one. I won't have good internet connection where I'm going, so I can't download anything from the Mac App Store. Is there a way I can easily transfer over my existing Xcode installation onto a large enough USB flashdrive and reinstall it that way. I know that I can drag and drop, but from my experience from MSVS, compilers and IDEs seems to have multiple dependency files scattered around.

Comment: When I bought my Mac there was CD to install all the extra software, haven't you got it? If not you need to copy the installer (a dmg file) and transfer it to your PC.

Comment: If you have an iOS or Mac developer program, you can download the Xcode install package without going through the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use Xcode 4 everything you *really* need, is in the Xcode.app bundle in your Applications folder. You can just copy this to your new computer.
If you want you can also copy `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Xcode` where plug-ins may reside.
An other interesting folder is `~/Library/Developer`. There are amongst others Docsests, iOS device logs, etc. stored. You may take a look yourself in there, to see if you need to copy this.

Answer (score 2):

Steps

1- Copy Xcode.app file and paste to new mac's `Application` folder

2- Copy `~/Library/Developer/` to new mac's location ~/Library/Developer/ folder

3-

> Issue - Xcode won't start, stuck on 'Verifying “Xcode”…'
>
> Solution  xattr -d com.apple.quarantine '/Applications/Xcode.app'

By running the above command, you are giving permission to Xcode to install it without verifying it.

4- open Xcode in the Application directory.

Cheers !!!!